# Can MVVM be used with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, model-view-intent

I mainly learned Android development with Jetpack Compose and MVI architecture. Now for learning purposes I am trying to understand the differences between MVI and MVVM and how MVVM could look like with Jetpack Compose.

I've read that one of the key features of MVVM is two way databinding. On Android however, two way data binding seems to be only available for the "old xml UI" world. Could MVVM still be used with Jetpack Compose? How would that look like in code?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state

Comment: @dominicoder That's an MVI example according to the section `6. Architecting your Compose UI` : "Unidirectional data flow" https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#5

Comment: It's literally titled "ViewModel and State in Compose." "State" being the model and "Compose" being the view. It says - "A unidirectional data flow (UDF) is a design pattern in which state flows down and events flow up." - It does not say say "this is MVI". MVI and MVVM are both _architectural_ patterns that use the UDF concept in slightly different ways.

Comment: When you pass State rather than ViewModel instance in the Composable Argument then it it known as MVI and when you pass ViewModel Instance itself in Composable Its known as MVVM

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MVVM can be used with Jetpack Compose, even without two-way data binding.

ViewModels in MVVM typically skip the complexity of actors, reducers, and similar constructs used in MVI, following a more streamlined approach. However, it’s worth noting that nothing stops developers from structuring a ViewModel in a MVI way if they prefer to do so.

Besides this, another small difference that sometimes comes up is in how the View communicates with the ViewModel, using independent methods for each interaction (`onEmailInputUpdated(…)`, `onSubmitSelected()`, etc.) compared to MVI where all of these would be modelled as a sealed class and passed through a single method to be processed.

In any case, both architectures depend on Unidirectional Data Flow (UDF). In Compose, that just means observing state changes in the ViewModel and recomposing the UI accordingly.

Two-way data binding, while useful as a sort of productivity tool for not having to manually update each view from your activity/fragment, doesn't really fundamentally affect the architectural communication between the View and the ViewModel. Whether you use data binding or not (which is deprecated in many contexts), it doesn't impact the core principles of MVVM.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! Do I understand correctly that in MVVM the `MVVM ViewModel` is a mutable state (in contrast to an immutable state on MVI)?

Comment: In MVVM, the term "ViewModel" might be misleading. It's not just about holding UI properties. VMs expose state through observables like LiveData, RxJava, or Kotlin Flows. The state, typically represented by immutable data classes, is updated by emitting new instances in response to user interactions, similar to MVI. So, the state in MVVM can definitely be immutable, with the UI observing these changes.

Still, MVVM's flexibility means you can choose your approach to state management: either bundle all state into a single observable or manage multiple streams for different fields @me.at.coding